# Why my selectbox custom jquery validation not working?

Tags: jquery-validate, drop-down-menu

I want to validate my selectboxes and I tried different approaches.

I don't want allow user to use default value = "Please select".

Validation is working only on first time, but when I'm submitting the form validation is passing.

My HTML select:

```
      <select id="website_category" name="website[category]" class="selectBox" style="display: none; "><option value="">--- please select ---</option>
       <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
       <option value="Computers">Computers</option>
```

<          Coupons
<

Here is my code:

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
   return value != param;
  }, "Please select something");
  ...
  'website[category]': {
              notEqual: "--- please select ---"
        },
```

also tried

```
 required:true
```

Here is what I get. When I choose default value  gives me:

[image]

but when I submit validation is passing:

[image]

WHY it is happening like that ? Can someone suggest right solution ?

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to set it to disabled like so:

```
<select id="website_category">
 <option value="-1" disabled selected="selected">---please select---</option>
  ....
</select>
```

Then you check for the value -1 both on client side and server side, just to be safe.

Once the user changes the selection, you cannot select the option again. This enforces error checking also.

Comment: I'm using Rails and generating select tag using helpers, I will try to do what you are talking about, thanks.

Comment: Also, I want to check it using ONLY jQuery validation plugin. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes. But you should be more concerned on server side. You can also hook your form using jQuery. If all the values are not valid you can call `preventDefault();` which cancels the default action for the object.